# React-Native <Text> omits the last character

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, text

Whenever I put a string of more than 5 characters inside a  element, the last one is not rendered.
Here's my code and the outputted string.

```
const Header = () => {
    const { textStyles, viewStyles } = styles;

    return (
        <View style={viewStyles}>
            <Text style={textStyles}>Albums</Text>        
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    viewStyles: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 15,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        elevation: 2
    },
    textStyles: {
        fontSize: 20
    },
};
```

Outputted string:
`Album`

If I change the string inside the Text element to something like `'Albums!'`, the output will be `Albums`. It always show n-1 characters.

Comment: Can you please share the styles object?

Comment: Just added the styles object :)

Comment: Strange! may be you are missing something else?

Comment: What is your device and OS version? I just had this bug reported on a production app.

Comment: I got the same problem... no issues on iOS, OnePlus3 or Samsung, but it does appear on my OnePlus6, did you found a solution?

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my OnePlus 6. I didn't experience the issue when I removed the alignItems-property.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code buddy Its working fine

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
  const { textStyles, viewStyles } = styles;

  return (
      <View style={viewStyles}>
          <Text style={textStyles}>Albums!!!!</Text>
      </View>
  );
};
export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header></Header>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyles: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 15,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        elevation: 2
    },
    textStyles: {
        fontSize: 20
    },
});
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I just added the styles object

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me.. I'm using a physical device to run  the app

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue on my OnePlus 6.
I fixed it by using `textAlign: "center"` instead of using `alignItems: "center"`.

I propose changing your `styles` to:

```
const styles = {
    viewStyles: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 15,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        elevation: 2
    },
    textStyles: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: "center"
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add all  components fontFamily: "" style just like this with empty value. Example:

```
<Text style={{color:'red', fontFamily: "", fontSize:20}}> Hasan Rıza UZUNER </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Manually applying a font may fix this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114)

[Here's how using expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts.html) / [Here's how in vanilla react native](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e)

If you don't feel like following those links, here's a quick rundown:

### 1. Acquire and add your font to your project

Make a new folder (eg. `assets/fonts/`) to hold your font's ttf files, [here's a link to roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto)

Copy your `.ttf` files directly into the directory you created (eg. `assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf`)

### 2. Link your fonts

Add rnpm asset configuration to your `package.json` (using your new folder from above, our example is `assets/fonts/` but you can use whatever folder you want.

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
  ]
}
```

Execute `react-native link` from your terminal

### 3. Use your font

From our example above we're using Roboto, replace Roboto with whatever font family you have downloaded. If you're on a mac and don't know the font family you can use the `font book.app` default app to find the name.

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto' }}>Some Text Here</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made just need to add width to either the text or the parent view

Answer (score 0):

May be you can wrap you  inside  and give width of '100%' to both tags.

```
    <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', width:'100%'}}>
       <Text style={{width:'100%', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize: 12, textAlign:'center'}}> Whatever the text you want to write here..!!</Text>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is still relevant.

I solved this issue by adding width to text element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using a Physical Samsung SE Series Device, and I enabled Bold font in the Settings of Android.

Just disabling it worked!

Comment: How do you do disable it?

Comment: That's what i told go to settings of your Samsung Device > Type Bold > Toggle the button to off.